# Issue using UrlResolver for component relative URLs - No provider for Token Application Packages Root URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to resolve the image URL's:

**app.module.ts code**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from "./app.routing";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { UrlResolver } from '@angular/compiler';

const routes: Routes = [
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders, UrlResolver
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.ts code:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { UrlResolver } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private urlResolver: UrlResolver) { }

    public resolvePath(path) {
        return this.urlResolver.resolve(module.id, path);
    }
}
```

I am providing UrlResolver, but the constructor injection of UrlResolver is causing error:

[image]

**app.component.html code**

```
 <img [src]="resolvePath('Logo.jpg')" alt="Logo" width="50" height="50">
```

why error on constructor injection, should I add anything in providers ?